# XML -> Excel Data Formatting

Tags: xml, excel

I shall start by listing my XML structure.

```
<root>
  <person>
    <birthday>
      03/24/1989
    </birthday>
    <money>
      $24.00
    </money>
  </person>
  <person>
    <birthday>
      03/24/1989
    </birthday>
    <money>
      $24.00
    </money>
  </person>
</root>
```

When I import this into excel, all the birthdays and money values are formatted as text.  I want to be able to apply filters to my table, such as birthdays between x & y or money values less than $13.00.  I can select a column and set the formatting, but it still doesn't enable the proper filter options.

Is there a way to make XML/Excel import data as anything other than text?  If not, is there a way to easily format the text to the desired format?

Comment: Select the column and choose *Format cells* once it's imported. There's no easier way to format the text.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file follows a particular and well-defined XSD (i.e., birthday as date, and money as currency), I think that will automatically take care of the correct data import. I try opening an XML file that I have with Excel, and everything is as should be.

Other than that, formatting the columns seems to be the way to go. I'm not sure what you mean by easily formatting, so maybe it will help if you can clarify a little bit more.

Comment: By easily formatting, I mean the method described by Ken White in the comment above.  However, doing what he has described does not apply the formatting.

Comment: Please try: import the data, then format the data (note: DO NOT format the headers), then apply filters